# How to set the maximum content length with akka's http client?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

If I try and download a very large file (over 100 MB) I get this error:

```
 You can configure this by setting `akka.http.[server|client].parsing.max-content-length` or calling `HttpEntity.withSizeLimit` before materializing the dataBytes stream.


val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
  Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
```

I was reading that I can somehow set the HttpEntity to `withoutSizeLimit`, how can I do this?

BTW, If I add those config settings to my application.config it doesn't solve the problem:

```
akka.http.server.parsing.max-content-length=913753229
akka.http.client.parsing.max-content-length=913753229
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the source code comments of `withSizeLimit(maxBytes: Long)` method in `akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity`:

> Note that the size limit applied via this method will only have any effect if the `Source` instance contained in this entity has been appropriately modified via the `HttpEntity.limitable` method. For all entities created by the HTTP layer itself this is always the case, but if you create entities yourself and would like them to properly respect limits defined via this method you need to make sure to apply `HttpEntity.limitable` yourself.

Maybe you need to convert the `Source` with `limitableByteSource()` method privided in `HttpEntity` object to make `withoutSizeLimit` take effect. There're some examples here: [akka http doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/misc-directives/withSizeLimit.html).

I ran with the same problem, but documentation has less useful information about why `withSizeLimit()` not work. Fortunately, source code provides the helpful info :-)